# How to disable SMS preview displayed over a locked screen?

Tags: sms, notifications, lock-screens

On an Android device (HTC Desire S if that matters) with a locked screen whenever an SMS is received it's preview is displayed over the locked screen. This is super inconvenient - anyone who is nearby can see it without even unlocking the screen.

Is there a way to disable those previews over a locked screen?

Comment: Is this a Sense thing or do you mean the status bar notification?

Comment: @onik: That's not status bar nofification, that's a huge preview box drawn right over the locked screen.

Comment: Ok, so it's a Sense feature. One pretty extreme solution would be to use CyanogenMod, which doesn't include this feature, but you'd also lose the other Sense additions. You can find more info at http://www.cyanogenmod.com

Answer (score 5):

You can do so by going into the Messaging app, and pressing Menu -> Settings -> Uncheck "Received notification (Show  notification in status bar when messages are received)".

But you won't get the notification on status bar as said above.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is to be done in the Messaging app.

Comment: Edited the answer for clarity at @onik's suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Settings > Privacy` and uncheck `Display Message Text`.

Comment: This seems like the best solution to me.

Comment: This is the one it sounds like they where after, As i too was searching for how to stop message text of arrived messages appearing on lock screen for all to read.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not terribly attached to the stock messaging app, install [GO SMS PRO](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jb.gosms&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5qYi5nb3NtcyJd) to handle your SMSes. It's better looking and infinitely more customisable than the stock app. [Handcent SMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms&hl=en) is another alternative SMS app.

Once you've installed GO SMS PRO, in the stock messaging app's Settings, uncheck everything. This should prevent double notifications.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've disabled the in-built notification as in [Roxan's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/18226/156), you could install an alternative SMS notifier app.

I use [SMS Popup](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.everythingandroid.smspopup) which still uses the in-built messaging app to handle all of your messaging, but gives a whole set of extra customizations to how you're notified. I have mine currently set to display the name and contact picture of the person that texted over the lock screen, but not show the message until the phone is unlocked.

Comment: Sweet! I'll also use this.

Answer (score 1):

The only way in the stock messaging application is to disable SMS notifications completely. 
As an alternative, you can install [GO SMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jb.gosms). It has the option to disable SMS preview in the notification bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Phone Settings -> Privacy, there is a check box for displaying messages on the lock screen.

Comment: Why the downvote? My method doesn't require any additional apps or work.  Just use the setting that is on the phone...

Comment: It was downvoted because its only present on some versions of Android, eg. its not available on mine.